# Error in fish script turns on bracketed paste mode for ssh session?

Tags: fish

When using a small fish function I’ve cobbled together (not a developer here, so please be gentle … ) for accessing a number of regularly needed ssh hosts, I’m seeing a strange effect: The bracket paste mode get’s activated for the ssh session.

This is the script:

```
function mssh

    set hosts host1 host2 host3 hostn
    
    set domain mydomain.com
    set user myusername
    set number (count $hosts)
    set numlength (string length $number)
    
    echo
    echo "Hosts:"
    echo
    for i in (seq $number)
        if test (string length "$i") -lt "$numlength"
            echo \t" "$i")" $hosts[$i]
        else
            echo \t$i")" $hosts[$i]
        end
    end
    echo
    
    while read --nchars $numlength -l response --prompt-str="Please select: "; or return 1
        if test "$response" -le "$number" 2>/dev/null
            ssh $user@$hosts[$response].$domain
            break
        else
            echo "Invalid selection"
            continue
        end
    end
    
end
```

With that, just for context, I was basically trying to reproduce the functionality of this zsh script (that I got from somewhere):

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

hosts=(host1 host2 host3)
domain="mydomain.com"
user="username"

PS3='Select: '
select host in ${hosts[@]}
do
    if [ "$host" = "" ]; then
        echo "Invalid selection."
    else
        ssh ${user}@${host}.${domain}
        break
    fi
done
```

But as I mentioned at the beginning my own script seems to be be somewhat erroneous at using it turns on fish’s bracket paste mode for the ssh session and everything I paste get’s wrapped in tilde characters (`~paste example~`).

It happens both in iTermin2 *and* the macOS terminal client.

It does not happen with the zsh script (or when I just call ssh directly).

Any pointers as to where I went wrong are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8285

Fish turns on bracketed paste mode for `read` (because you could be pasting something in there).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I’ll wait for the fix, then. 